# Toggle isn't sliding the first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, slide

i need to do a toogle on jquery, but the first time the toogle runs, the loaded data just pops-up. The following clicks they slide ... what can i do ?

here is my code ...

```
function visita(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "VisitaAjaxGerenciar.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: ({
            visita_id : id    
            }),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                $('#visitaAjax_'+id).toggle( "slide" ).html(data);
                //ajaxJQuery();
            }

        });
    }
```

thanks for the help : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#visitaAjax_'+id).toggle( "slide" ).html(data);
```

To:

```
$('#visitaAjax_'+id).html(data).toggle( "slide" );
```

Probably because before this ajax callback the element is empty and you don't see the slide on the element as it is empty, so set the html first and then do toggle in your callback.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nfEh3/)**

Comment: ohh Yeah, It worked :) !! Thanks a lot man , i was trying everything and nothing was working ...